# How does a question get marked as closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

I'm just wondering how does a question get marked as closed? In the FAQ it states you can vote to close a question past 250, but what does that mean exactly? It doesn't state who/how a question gets marked as closed.

Also, what does it mean once a question is closed, do they get purged after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Why is this question voted down?  Seems like a reasonable question?

Comment: Probably because it's been asked at least a dozen times.  I can't say for sure as I'm neither the downvoter nor telepathic, but that seems the most likely reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing a question effectively means that it can't be added to or answered. The question can however still be edited and commented on. This normally happens if it is a duplicate question, or various other reasons depending on the site.

The voting process works differently depending on your level.

- 250+ allows you to vote to close your own questions. The change still requires 4 more votes.
- 3000+ rep users can vote to close, and 5 votes are needed until the question is closed.
- Diamond moderators can close immediatly.

These question remain in the system, and can either be voted to be re-open or deleted. The same voting rules apply for these options.

Only deleted questions are removed from the system after 3 days if memory serves.

Comment: Thank you Diago, much appreciated.

Comment: I think you still need 4 others to vote to close your own questions too - but it might have changed since I last tried it.

Comment: @ChrisF - Had to go to SO to test this but yes, if you vote to close your own question it requires 4 more votes before it is closed.

Comment: Isn't it embarrassing for a moderator to be asking a question that needs to be closed?

Comment: @devinb - Why would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, it's the ability to vote to close *your own questions* that appears at 250 rep.

Comment: +1 Ammended my answer accordingly.